# Add class based on if statement

Tags: html, if-statement

I have a blog which has **ten blog tags** (ten categories).

I'm using `isotope`, so when each blog category is filtered, it will show the relevant blogs (one's with matching tags).

So for example: If I filter my blogs by the tag **Indoor air quality**, I want to add the class `indoor-air-quality` to the div etc. If a post has more than one tag, I want it to add the relevant two classes.

Here is my current approach (**note**: the following is HubL (HubSpot language):

```html
{% for content in contents %}

     <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 post all
                  
          {% for tag in content.tag_list %}
             {% set company_tag = 'company' %}
             {% set humidity_tag = 'humidity-indoor-air-quality' %}
             {% set air_tag = 'indoor-air-quality' %}
             {% set news_tag = 'news' %}
             {% set reviews_tag = 'reviews' %}
             {% set tech_tag = 'tech' %}
             {% set vlog_tag = 'vlog' %}

             {% if tag == "Company" %}
                {% set tag_name == company_tag %}
             {% endif %}
                  
             {% if tag == "Humidity" %}
                 {% set tag_name == humidity_tag %}
             {% endif %}
                  
             {% if tag == "Indoor Air Quality" %}
                  {% set tag_name == air_tag %}
             {% endif %}
                  
             {% if tag == "News" %}
                  {% set tag_name == news_tag %}
             {% endif %} 
                  
             {% if tag == "Product Reviews" %}
                  {% set tag_name == reviews_tag %}
             {% endif %}  
                  
             {% if tag == "Tech" %}
                  {% set tag_name == tech_tag %}
               {% endif %}
                  
             {% if tag == "Vlog" %}
                  {% set tag_name == vlog_tag %}
                {% endif %}  
                   
            {{ tag_name }}
      
        ">
        
        {% endfor %}
```

Currently, no class is being added to my div?

Comment: this is twig oui? pure-HTML has no conditionals

Comment: You need to make it clear what language you are using, and tag the question appropriately.  Those look like twig tags, but _could be anything_ - so please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: Yes, from what I've heard, HubL is very similar to twig. I have referenced HubL in my question and no tag exists for HubL on here. Either way, I think the basic premise of my if statements is what is the issue

Comment: have you tried doing your conditional at the top of your doc and then just echo the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing (`==`) instead of assigning the variables (`=`) outside of your if statements, so they will always be undefined.

```
{% set company_tag == 'company' %}
```

should be

```
{% set company_tag = 'company' %}
```

Comment: So `{% set vlog_tag = 'vlog' %}` instead of `{% set vlog_tag == 'vlog' %}`?

Comment: should this not be flagged as a typo then instead of answered?

Comment: @Freddy Yes. treyBake why not both?

Comment: @D_N because typos are off-topic

Comment: The OP and others searching similarly still need an answer.

Comment: @D_N then comment - it doesn't really benefit anyone to have typos as questions ..

Comment: It’s helped me in the past. Esp. when new to things. Typos are not all created equal (or transparent).

Comment: ... I've changed `==` to `=` for everything outside my if statement and it still doesn't print any class name for me? I've even converted everything to `=`, same results

Comment: @Freddy - update your question with the _actual_ code, and as a side-note, update your question to respond to the questions in the comments.  It's pretty imposslbe for D_N to continue to help while "guessing" what you've got in place.

Comment: Don’t convert everything to =. Only change the top ones (that should be assigning the variables) to it, and leave the rest as in your answer. I’ll be happy to look back at it.

Comment: Yup that's what I did initially, question has been updated :)

Comment: @Freddy the trouble may be in your data that you loop through instead of in your if statements if the above does not work. Make sure you are getting what you expect in those if statements (Capitalized strings).

Comment: @Freddy the variable assignments (`set`) inside the if blocks need to be `=` as well

Comment: @treyBake see? not exactly a mere typo.

Comment: @D_N at the time of posting - it would appear to be a typo .. now it's just veering into too broad/unclear xD

Comment: @Freddy read `==` as “is the same as” and `=` as “is from now on equal to”. Only use == in if statements (if x is the same as y).

Comment: @D_N ah, I did an print of `tag` and the correct tag's are pulling up, but yes, changing to `=` in (`set`) seems to have done the trick! much appreciated :)